# Does $\omega$ in photons energy formula equals $|\psi|^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Does $\omega$ in photons energy formula $E=\hbar\omega$ equals $|\psi|^2$ ?

($\hbar$ - Dirac's const)

Comment: Did you mean $h$ is Planck's constant?

Comment: @JohnRennie, no Dirac's constant. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: @ArturKlochko I think you mean the reduced planck constant - this is just Planck's constant divided by $2\pi$, and is not often referred to as the Dirac constant as you can tell by Johns reaction!

Comment: The closest association would seem to be reflected in Wikipedia's article on the [Klein–Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation), $$\left< E \right> =\left< \psi \middle| i \hbar {\frac {\partial}{\partial t}} \middle| \psi \right> =\hbar \omega \,.$$Was that what you were thinking of?

Comment: @Nat, well, I just trying to understand what does exactly this *w* means

Comment: Ohhh, you just wanna know the definition of $\omega$?  It's just $2 \pi \nu$, where $\nu$ is the photon's frequency.  $\omega$ is called the [angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency).

Comment: @Nat, yeah, and how could it has a particle, that actually is a point?

Comment: That's [wave–particle duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality).  Basically a photon isn't considered to be a true particle or a true wave, but rather some fuzzy combination of both concepts.  Many regard resolving this apparent paradox as an unsolved problem.

Comment: @Nat, I'm confused. Photon is an electromagnetic field oscillation. It's like a one full oscillation? If it has frequency there should be 2 and more oscilation, right?

Comment: You can ask a new question about something like that if you'd like.  Getting a variety of  perspectives may be particularly helpful in finding a grounding for this topic.

Comment: See this  for the maxwell wavefunction of the photon http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002?ln=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumptions I make:** (I have to define a framework, sorry...)

1) $\psi$ is the scalar photon wave-function

2) since we associate a photon with a wave-function, we are, probably, in quantum mechanics formalism

3) let's say, we consider the case of a monochromatic plane wave for simplicity (and because this is the only thing that really works well in QM...)

**Conclusions:**

In this case, what has been mentioned earlier:

|$\langle E \rangle| = |\langle \psi | i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}| \psi \rangle| = \hbar \omega$

is true by construction, as $E=\hbar \omega$ is an experimental fact, that has been postulated in the foundation of QM representation of quantum of light.

But, please, remember that wave functions have **almost nothing** to do with the actual observables ($\omega, \lambda$, intensity etc.), except, they provide a basis expansion for the operators (that can (!) correspond to the observables) in Hilbert space and normalized to probability to detect the particle in a certain point in physical space (well, kind of). Assigning a concrete physical meaning to $\psi$ is strictly speaking a complete nonsense. Especially for a photon, whose position is undefined...

**Analogy**

You have a vector of unit length $|\vec{a}| = 1$. Let's say, you use the conventional 2D coordinate system of your choice. Then, your vector can be decomposed into $\vec{a} = 0 \hat{i} + 1\hat{j}$. Now I come and say that in my coordinate system it is $\vec{a}' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( -1\hat{i}- 1\hat{j})$. What physical significance does your $1\hat{i}$ $1\hat{j}$; and my $1/\sqrt{2}\hat{i}$ $1/\sqrt{2}\hat{j}$ have? The same as $\psi$ in QM - none. Those are just basis expansion coefficients with the corresponding direction vectors that have nothing to do with an actual physical vector. That vector exists in the same state whether you expand it or not. What's important is the norm. Now, instead of heaving a deterministic norm (equal to some number), in QM we have a distribution. That is it.

Comment: Thank You a lot. I'm just starting learn all this stuff, but why You, for example wrote, that unit vectors in two different frames, do not mean anything, if we can translate with them coordinates, from one to another? Or can't? Oh, and what does ***i*** in your formula means, and triangular brackets?

Comment: @Artur Klochko By "mean nothing" I mean they don't have a physical significance. In different reference frames and bases those numbers will be absolutely different. But the norm of any vector is conserved under coordinate transformations and has a well-defined physical meaning.

Comment: @Artur Klochko Do you mean $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$? Those are directional unit vectors in the coordinate system of choice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector

Comment: About vector understood, and ***i***, I meant in formula with psi(without a hat)

Comment: @Artur Klochko Complex $i$: $i^2=-1$.

Comment: @Artur Klochko You could benefit from reading what energy operator is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_operator

Comment: One moment: you gived a formula that determs photons energy, by psi function, but there is no photon psi function and position of photon is undefiend, because of its zero mass.

Comment: @Artur Klochko There is a photon wave function defined in QM. You can consult Landau Lifshitz E&M for that.

Answer (score 3):

No. $\omega$ and $\psi$ have very little to do with one another. They don't even have the same units: $\omega$ has units of $\rm s^{-1}$, and the units of $\psi$ depend on what exactly you mean by $\psi$: for instance, if you mean the position-space wavefunction, $\psi(x)$, the units are $\rm m^{-3/2}$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77635/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-does-omega-in-photons-energy-formula-equals).